# CZML polygon without color or material

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, czml

Is it possible to draw a CZML polygon with only polygon outline and no material to cover the sides of polygon?

This is required as my requirement is to enable clicking on an object completely immersed into the polygon, i.e., no side of inner polygon overlaps the side of outer polygon.  So I just want to draw a polygon outline to make the inner polygon listen click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much @emackey for your descriptive answer. Your answer is useful for that I want to increase the width of polygon outline.

But the easier way to achieve hollow polygon (polygon with only outline) is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum%2Fcesium-dev&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&hideforumtitle=true&fragments=true&parenturl=https%3A%2F%2Fcesiumjs.org%2Fforum.html#!searchin/cesium-dev/CZML$20polygon$20without$20material/cesium-dev/C5w65dkIYUc/zawP7YZ2AQAJ). Setting `fill` property of CZML polygon to `false` worked for me.

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, yes, you can set the polygon's interior color to be completely transparent, such that only the outline is visible or clickable.  There are downsides to this approach that I'll explain below, but first, here's a working example:

```
var czml = [{
    "id" : "document",
    "name" : "CZML Geometries: Polygon",
    "version" : "1.0"
}, {
    "id" : "outlinedPolygon",
    "name" : "Outlined Polygon",
    "polygon" : {
        "positions" : {
            "cartographicDegrees" : [
                -108.0, 25.0, 0,
                -100.0, 25.0, 0,
                -100.0, 30.0, 0,
                -108.0, 30.0, 0
            ]
        },
        "material" : {
            "solidColor" : {
                "color" : {
                    "rgba" : [0, 0, 0, 0]
                }
            }
        },
        "extrudedHeight" : 0,
        "perPositionHeight" : true,
        "outline" : true,
        "outlineColor" : {
            "rgba" : [255, 255, 0, 255]
        }
    }
}];

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var dataSource = Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml);
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
viewer.zoomTo(dataSource);
```

Now the problem:  Many Windows-based systems and other WebGL implementations don't allow line widths other than exactly `1.0` pixels.  This means your polygon will always have a thin outline on many systems.

Another downside is the renderer will probably still consider and then discard all of those transparent fragments from the interior of the polygon, which could hurt performance.

A solution to both is to use a [Polyline](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML%20Polyline.html&label=CZML) instead of a Polygon to draw the outline.  Cesium has a custom-built system for drawing polylines as screen-space polygons, avoiding the 1-pixel WebGL line limitations that affect many users.  Also, Polylines will not attempt to fill in an enclosed area in any way.

You do have to repeat the first point as the last point to cause the polyline to fully enclose an area.  Here's an example:

```
var czml = [{
    "id" : "document",
    "name" : "CZML Geometries: Polyline",
    "version" : "1.0"
}, {
    "id" : "outlinedPolygon",
    "name" : "Outlined Polygon",
    "polyline" : {
        "positions" : {
            "cartographicDegrees" : [
                -108.0, 25.0, 0,
                -100.0, 25.0, 0,
                -100.0, 30.0, 0,
                -108.0, 30.0, 0,
                -108.0, 25.0, 0
            ]
        },
        "width": 5,
        "material" : {
            "solidColor" : {
                "color" : {
                    "rgba" : [255, 255, 0, 255]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}];

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var dataSource = Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml);
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
viewer.zoomTo(dataSource);
```